# Difference between initrd.img and a initramfs.img?

Tags: linux, initramfs, initrd

an initrd.img sets the stage for the real root file system to take over once done, as I understand it the initramfs.img is a customizable version of the initrd. lets say you are loading to a diskless target can an initramfs.img contain the actual root directory and its files?

Question1:   I know how to add nfs and other kernel modules to the initramfs when creating it but is there a way to load the root file system into this .img or does it just automatically do that using the root of the the running machine?

Question2: when using a initramfs is the root file system that is pointed to by say a pxe server provided in additon to this initramfs.img just for persistent storage?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that your question is formatted in a way that makes it unpleasant to read; you may want to edit it to give it more structure (paragraphs, lists etc.) so that contributors can more easily see what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks and will do ill make an edit

Comment: *initramfs* is a concept. It can be and do anything you tell it to do, see for example [Custom Initramfs](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs) - if you want to ask about a specific flavor / implementation of an initramfs, you should add a link to it. Right now from your question alone it's quite unclear what you are referring to.